# How do I deal with this Haskell difficulty?

Tags: haskell

I'm a new in Haskell and i studied by myself, I'm running program but I don't understand for loop to much. In my program I did While loop,and I'm going to show my work for both but I need explain someone explain for loop how to do this sentence which i made 
`(let x = ref 0 in ( for (i=1 to 10 )(x:=deref x+i)));deref x )`. There is some variable I use 
i can show it to you guys if you want.
I did While loop like this and it works

```
interp env (While b1 b2)  = do
  c1 <- interp env b1
  case c1 of
    (VBool True)  -> do
                         interp env b2
                         interp env (While b1 b2)
    (VBool False) -> return VNil
```

However, my work for loop is

```
interp env ( For s a1 a2 a3)= do 
  v1 <- interp env a1
  v2 <- interp env a2 
  if  (v1<v2 ) then do 
    x <- interp env a1
    let env' = extendEnv x e1 env 
    interp env' a3 
  else return VNil
```

but is not working, Please can you explain what's wrong?

Comment: How does this question relate to java?

Comment: anyone can say something Please ?

Comment: It might help if you told us what happened.  Compiler error?  What did you expect?

Comment: The biggest suggestion is to stop thinking in Java and translating to Haskell.  You need to learn to think in Haskell.  Try solving a problem without using the IO monad for anything except actual input and output.

Comment: Thanks,, I mean this (let x = ref 0 in ( for (i=1 to 10 )(x:=deref x+i)));deref x ) should give me 55.

Comment: I have a new answer but not correct yet.

Comment: You seem to be writing a mini-interpreter.  It might help if we had a bit more context.  You don't seem to be using "s", which is presumably supposed to be the loop variable.

Comment: I don't understand but while woks this mean my work correct still for loop

Comment: Seriously, read this before you ask anything again. Please: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Also, if you are new to Haskell and studied by yourself, how is it that you seem to have come to be writing a mini-interpreter that seems to match a current assignment at chalmers? http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2010/course/TIN321/lectures/proglang-08.html

Comment: Ah, the desperate cry of the CS student. Like the swallows return to Capistrano, their honk resounds through the message boards at the end of every term.

Answer (score 2):

I am making the following assumptions in this answer, as not enough information is given to answer properly:

- You have a `VInt` data constructor much like `VBool` in your question. I assume it holds a single value of type `Int`.
- `extendEnv` takes three parameters. This first is a variable ID (of unknown type), the second is the expression to bind it to (or value if this language isn't lazy, of unknown type), the third is the environment you are extending (of, surprise surprise, unknown type).
- The input AST has been type checked, so I'm not handling type errors.

Code:

```
interp env (For var start end body) = do 
    (VInt s) <- interp env start
    (VInt e) <- interp env end 
    if s < e 
      then
          let nenv = extendEnv var start env in do
              interp nenv body
              interp nenv (For var (VInt (s - 1)) end body) -- Maybe only env here.
      else return VNil
```

Comment: Looking back, it would seem I forgot to interpret the body for some reason. Fixed now, though I should be able to give a better answer if you improve the question...

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same problem, but maybe I can give a little more context in what is going on for my situation and maybe that can help.

Creating an interpreter with typedef:

```
interp :: Env -> Expr -> M Val
```

that handles **for** loops in this format:

```
for ( var = expr to expr ) ( expr )
```

Data constructor defined as the following:

```
data Val =
   ValInt Int
 | ValBool Bool
 | ValFun (Val -> M Val)
 | ValRecFun (Val -> Val -> M Val)
 | ValRef Loc
 | ValNil
```

And an extended environment defined as:

```
extendEnv :: Identifier -> Val -> Env -> Env
extendEnv var val (Env bs) = Env ((var,val):bs)
```

Here's where I am:

```
interp env (For x e1 e2 e3)       = do
                                      (ValInt v1) <- interp env e1
                                      (ValInt v2) <- interp env e2
                                      if (v1 < v2)
                                        then 
                                            let nenv = extendEnv x e1 env in do
                                                interp nenv e3
                                                interp env (For x e1 e2 e3)
                                        else return ValNil
```

Obviously, I don't want to pass "e1" into the recursive call of the for loop, but rather the evaluated "v1" variable incremented.... but I can't figure out how to pass it the correct expression of "v1".  Is this enough direction to get a little help?:)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to state what's wrong with your for loop using only the code you've provided (type error?).  However, if you really insist on mutable state, I would write your for loop

```
(let x = ref 0 in ( for (i=1 to 10 )(x:=deref x+i)));deref x )
```

as

```
import Control.Monad.State

forloop = snd $ runState (forM_ [1..10] incr) 0

incr n = modify (+n)
```

I probably wouldn't bother trying to abstract any further than this.